# Convert MKV to HLS with all audio tracks and subtitles available

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, video-encoding, ffmpeg-filters

For the past few weeks, I've been trying to convert MKV and HLS files. Currently, I'm burning the first available subtitle track of the file in the video and keeping only the first audio track.

What i would like to do : Input an MKV file and convert it to HLS while keeping all the audio tracks and all the subtitle tracks of the MKV file in question.

So, I'd like to know how to: input an MKV file to convert it to HLS while keeping all the audio tracks and subtitles in the MKV file in question, and then group them together in a master.m3u8 file that would include the video, audio and subtitles.

I've read the ffmpeg documentation, but as I've only been using it for a short time, I can't manage to do this.

Thanks to anyone who can help or give me advice.

Have a nice day

I tried using ffprobe to get information about the MKV.

I then selected the audio/subtitle tracks and tried to make a loop in python/PHP-ffmpeg to extract the subtitles in WebVTT format and the same for the audio tracks, then linked the whole thing once the video had been converted to HLS.

I got nothing but errors, the script just didn't work...

Comment: It will be usefull that you show what you have tried and what errors you got.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you've tried before, what I understand is you need to convert an mkv file to hls while keeping it's original quality, audio tracks and subtitles using python/php-ffmpeg.

**Python (using subprocess):**

```
import subprocess

input_file = 'path/to/your/mkv.mkv'
output_dir = 'path/to/output/directory'

command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', input_file,
    '-c:v', 'copy',  # Preserve original video quality
    '-c:a', 'copy',  # Preserve original audio tracks
    '-c:s', 'mov_text',  # Convert subtitles to WebVTT
    '-hls_list_size', '0',  # Create a single master playlist
    '-f', 'hls',
    output_dir + '/out.m3u8'
]

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Monitor progress (example using a simple counter)
progress = 0
while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
    if not line:
        break
    # Extract progress information from the output (if available)
    # and update your UI accordingly
    progress += 1  # Or use a more sophisticated progress tracking method
    print(line, end='')

process.wait()
print('HLS conversion completed!')
```

**PHP-FFmpeg:**

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

$video = $ffmpeg->open('path/to/your/mkv.mkv');

$format = new FFMpeg\Format\HLS();
$format->setSegmentLength(10);  # Adjust segment length as needed
$format->setListSize(0);  # Create a single master playlist

$video->save($format, 'path/to/output/directory/out.m3u8');
```